# Showing discontinuity by open and closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Define the function $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$. I want to find an open resp. closed set in $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that the inverse image under $f$ is not open resp. closed. Moreover I want to find $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $f(\overline{A})\nsubseteq\overline{f(A)}$. Can one help me with searching for such sets? Thanks.

Comment: Well, $f(\mathbb{R}^+)=\{0,1\}$. You do not have many choices...